# Deleting items from a python dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a spam classification application in Python but i'm getting the errors below. I don't understand it though since i'm using the .keys method to delete items from the dictionary so that shouldn't be a problem?
I've tried removing all the functionars bar the dictionary function to try and find a cause but I can't seem to wrap my head around this

Python code

```
    import os
    import numpy as np
    from collections import Counter
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

    def make_Dictionary(train_dir):
        emails = [os.path.join(train_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(train_dir)]    
        all_words = []       
        for mail in emails:    
            with open(mail) as m:
                for i,line in enumerate(m):
                    if i == 2:
                        words = line.split()
                        all_words += words

        dictionary = Counter(all_words)

        list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()
        for item in list_to_remove:
            if item.isalpha() == False: 
                del dictionary[item]
            elif len(item) == 1:
                del dictionary[item]
        dictionary = dictionary.most_common(3000)
        return dictionary

    def extract_features(mail_dir): 
        files = [os.path.join(mail_dir,fi) for fi in os.listdir(mail_dir)]
        features_matrix = np.zeros((len(files),3000))
        docID = 0;
        for fil in files:
          with open(fil) as fi:
            for i,line in enumerate(fi):
              if i == 2:
                words = line.split()
                for word in words:
                  wordID = 0
                  for i,d in enumerate(dictionary):
                    if d[0] == word:
                      wordID = i
                      features_matrix[docID,wordID] = words.count(word)
            docID = docID + 1     
        return features_matrix

    # Create a dictionary of words with its frequency

    train_dir = r'.\train-mails'
    dictionary = make_Dictionary(train_dir)

    # Prepare feature vectors per training mail and its labels

    train_labels = np.zeros(702)
    train_labels[351:701] = 1
    train_matrix = extract_features(train_dir)

    # Training SVM and Naive bayes classifier and its variants

    model1 = LinearSVC()


    model1.fit(train_matrix,train_labels)


    # Test the unseen mails for Spam

    test_dir = r'.\test-mails'
    test_matrix = extract_features(test_dir)
    test_labels = np.zeros(260)
    test_labels[130:260] = 1

    result1 = model1.predict(test_matrix)


    print (confusion_matrix(test_labels,result1))
    print (confusion_matrix(test_labels,result2))
```

Error

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in Python 3.x because `keys` returns an iterator instead of a list.

Another way is to use list to force a copy of the keys to be made. This one also works in Python 3.x:

```
for i in list(list_to_remove):
```

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary.keys()` is actually returning a reference to the original dictionary keys.

You can check this by doing the following:

```
 a_dict = {'a': 1}
 keys = a_dict.keys() # keys is dict_keys(['a'])
 a_dict['b'] = 2 # keys is dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
```

That's why you are getting the error: with `del dictionary[item]` you are actually affecting `list_to_remove`, which is forbidden during a loop.

You can avoid this by creating a copy of the original keys before looping through them. The easiest way to achieve this is using the `list` constructor. So changing your line

```
list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()
```

with:

```
list_to_remove = list(dictionary.keys())
```

solves the issue.

**Edition after comment**

Note that this behaviour only happens in `python 3`, in `python 2`, the `.keys()` method returned a normal list, with no reference to the dictionary:

```
a_dict = {'a': 1}
keys = a_dict.keys() # keys is ['a']
a_dict['b'] = 2 # keys is still ['a']
```

About this on the Python 3.0 [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists):

> Some well-known APIs no longer return lists:
>
> - dict methods dict.keys(), dict.items() and dict.values() return “views” instead of lists.

Comment: thankyou for the answer! that seems to solve it. Any reason why the whole thing just crashes, aka not working. It comes straight from a github page that should work.

Comment: Oh, yes! I forgot that. You are using `python 3`, which returns this reference `dict_keys` and the code you copied is `python 2`, where the `keys()` method returned a list. I'll add it to my answer now.

Comment: awesome, that makes sense. Apart from rolling back to python 2 what would you suggest?

Comment: This is one of the largest changes from python 2 to 3 and if it's not too much code it may work directly or with some [fixes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html). On the other hand, typically both `python3` and `python2.7` can coexist in a linux environment, so you can try to run this code with `python2.7` instead of `python` which is the default. If `python2.7` is not present probably you could install it on the side of python 3. I mean, there is no need to "rollback".